# Altium : keepout polygon on all layers

Tags: altium

On a 4 layers pcb, I placed a pcb antenna.
I don't want any copper below the antenna whather the layer.

I tried to add a keepout layer but I did not find a way to make it
active for all layers, including plane layers.
Is there a way to?

Edit:
I tried to add the keepout region to keepout layer:
[image]

It works well for top and bottom layer:
[image]
[image]

But not for internal layers. Here's the groung plane:
[image]
Gerber export confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

Set your keepout layer to *Keep-Out Layer* in the properties pull down menu. This will place the keepout on all layers. The *Keep-Out Layer* is a standard layer in Altium. True to Altium's [documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-obj-regionkeepoutregion-keepout-ad), this is not clearly documented.

[image] 
Screen shot from Altium showing setting for keepout on all layers.

Comment: I tried this before but I wasn't sucessfull. I updated the question.

Comment: @Julien Keepouts work only on polygon pours. Keepouts will not work on plane layers. Unfortunately, you need to draw voids in each of the plane layers to accomplish what you want. I've found that Altium has really poor control over plane layers if you need to write rules for plane layers (not documented) and/or need to divide the plane in to different nets. In those cases where the plane layer is complex, use a pour(s) instead of a plane layer. It will save you much anguish.